# What is the possible use of dev_set_drvdata and dev_get_drvdata

Tags: linux-device-driver

I just want to know what is the possible use case when we have to use these set and get driver APIs.
All I get to know that the data is saved, and at a later time we can use data to do something. My question is when we really need to do that?

```c
     /*
      * These exports can't be _GPL due to .h files using this within them, and it
      * might break something that was previously working...
     */
     void *dev_get_drvdata(const struct device *dev)
     {
          if (dev && dev->p)
                  return dev->p->driver_data;
          return NULL;
     }
     EXPORT_SYMBOL(dev_get_drvdata);

     void dev_set_drvdata(struct device *dev, void *data)
     {
        int error;
 
        if (!dev)
                 return;
        if (!dev->p) {
                 error = device_private_init(dev);
                 if (error)
                         return;
        }
        dev->p->driver_data = data;
     }
     EXPORT_SYMBOL(dev_set_drvdata);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The driver core handles different stages of running the driver. You may consider a driver code as a set of callbacks, such as `->probe()`, `->remove()`, and so on. For details you can check `struct platform_driver` or `struct pci_driver` definition.

So, how can you communicate between the callbacks?

Right, you have at least two ways:

- introduce global variable in the module [usually BAD idea]
- specify something in the parameters of callback, in your case `struct device` or its children (`struct pci_dev` for example).

Thus, we have a pointer to a private member which can be used as a container of useful information that should be passed through callbacks.

Why we need that? Most of the drivers request some resources and save pointers to them somewhere at `probe` stage. To avoid a leak of the resources you have to free them at the `remove` stage. That's how it used.

As pointed out by [allsey87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5164339/allsey87), another useful pattern is to pass a current state of the device across callbacks. One of the real example is power management callbacks (`->suspend()`, `->resume()`, etc).

Interestingly the author of the [Linux Misc Device: general protection fault at `misc_deregister()` on driver with private data allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76732523/2511795) question tried to use driver data of the miscelleneous device (which is available via the `this_device` member of `struct miscdevice`). However, [as we may see](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5-rc3/source/drivers/char/misc.c#L242), the misc device framework uses that field for its own needs and user must not intervene that. The correct approach in such cases is to embed the `struct miscdevice` into your custom structure and use `container_of()` approach (remembering that Linux kernel is written in OOP paradigm). Example:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5-rc3/source/lib/test_kmod.c#L121 (definition), https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5-rc3/source/lib/test_kmod.c#L153 (getter).

Comment: This is a good answer, I would also add a little bit of detail regarding the most common use pattern where a device kernel module defines a struct that represents the state of the device's instance which is allocated using `devm_kzalloc` and stored for retrieval in the callbacks using  `dev_set_drvdata` and `dev_get_drvdata`.

Comment: @allsey87, I have added a paragraph.