# How to use container_of() when the variable is in a struct within a struct?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have browsed lots of questions regarding to `container_of()`, but did not find a question asking how to retrieve a struct within a struct using `container_of()`. If this question is duplicate, please point it out. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I am currently implementing a PCI device driver remove() function combined with another kernel module, with the following setup (I eliminated some other fields to make this question easy to read):

```
struct my_device {
    struct mutex lock;
    
    struct my_dev {
        struct cdev cdev;
    } my_dev;
    
    struct pci {
        struct cdev cdev;
        struct pci_dev *pdev;
    } pci;
};
```

Here comes the question: **When we have a pointer to pdev within struct pci of type `struct pci_dev *`, how could we get `struct pci`, then get `struct my_device`?** Note that in `probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)`, I had assigned `dev` to a previously allocated `struct my_device *dev_ptr`, i.e. `dev_ptr->pci.pdev = dev;`

I tried the following:

```
struct pci *pci_t;
pci_t = container_of(ptr, struct pci, pdev)
```

but that did not work.

The error message is as follows:

```
error: call to '__compiletime_assert_243' declared with attribute error: pointer type mismatch in container_of()
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

Updates:

I tried the approaches in the comments. Since the remove() function of pci driver has a parameter - `struct pci_dev *dev`, which represents the corresponding pci device, I did the following:

```
struct my_device *mydev;
mydev = container_of(&dev, struct my_device, pci.pdev);
```

But it did not return the pointer to the correct structure to `mydev`.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  that shows how exactly you use that macro and also show the exact error message.

Comment: Maybe not causing the problem, but "a pointer to `pdev` within `struct pci`" must be of type `struct pci_dev **`, not `struct pci_dev*`

Comment: @Gerhardh That's a good point, it's quite possible that might be the problem  Ethan, try fixing your incorrect declaration, and see if that helps.

Comment: The updated question still does not show a complete sample how that macro is used. The types of variables are unknown.

Comment: @Gerhardh - Yeah it compiled successfully. Could you please tell me the reason of the type of pointer to ```pdev``` being ```struct pci_dev **```?

Comment: For the same reason why a pointer to `int` is of type `int *`. You need a pointer to `struct pci_dev*` which is `struct pci_dev**`

Comment: @Gerhardh - I see why I had such mistake. I did not fully understand the first parameter of ```container_of()```, which caused the problem.

Comment: If you have a wrong pointer type, how could you get the address assigned to it, to start with? If you try to do `struct pci_dev *ptr = &xy.pci.pdev;`  you should also get a warning about pointer type mismatch.

Comment: @EthanL. if the struct member had type `int`, you would need an `int *` pointer, right?  But if it had type `int *`, you would need an `int **` pointer.  In your case, it has type `struct pci_dev *`, so you need a `struct pci_dev **` pointer.  If you want a pointer to a type, the pointer needs one added level of indirection than that type.   You really need to understand this.  This is fundamental to C.

Comment: All commentators missed an important detail, i.e. you are talking about the Linux kernel. So, the right solution for you is to keep driver data filled with the pointer to **the certain instance** of the `struct pci` or better `struct my_device`. Do not uglify your code with double pointers and so, please! More to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800337/what-is-the-possible-use-of-dev-set-drvdata-and-dev-get-drvdata/

Comment: You should be using `pci_set_drvdata` to associate a pointer to your `struct my_device` (or your `struct pci`) with the PCI device (pointed to by a `struct pci_device *`), and use `pci_get_drvdata` to retrieve that pointer from the PCI device. Alternatively, replace `pci_set_drvdata` and `pci_get_drvdata` with `dev_set_drvdata` and `dev_get_drvdata` using the address of the `struct device dev` embedded in the `struct pci_device`.

Comment: FWIW, if you actually had a pointer `p` that is the address of the `pdev` member (rather than `p` being the *value* of the `pdev` member), you could get to the `struct my_device` in one leap using `struct my_device *mydev = container_of(p, struct my_device, pci.pdev);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Your comment is the most useful one. Appreciate it. I understand that using ```pci_set/get_drvdata()``` is one solution that would work, as I have seen those two functions in many driver codes, but I am still curious about why using ```container_of()``` does not work in this case. I have updated my original question with some more details about what parameter I passed in - in short, I passed in the address of the pointer to ```struct pci_dev```, i.e. the parameter of ```remove()```.

Comment: The updated version did not work because `&dev` is the address of the function parameter, not the address of the `mydev->pci.pdev` member. `container_of()` basically works by using pointer arithmetic to subtract the offset of a member from the address of a member to get the address of the member's container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified definition of the `container_of()` macro:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))
```

The `offsetof(type, member)` macro is as described in the C standard and gives the number of bytes from the start of some structure type `type` to the start of some member of that type `member`. `ptr` *should* be compatible with a pointer to the type of the member (but the simplified version above does not care). `(char *)(ptr)` converts the pointer to a byte pointer pointing to the member so that the pointer subtraction `(char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)` produces a byte pointer to the start of the containing structure type. Finally, the cast `(type *)` converts that pointer to the proper type.

An example of usage.  Given:

```
struct my_device {
    struct mutex lock;
    
    struct my_dev {
        struct cdev cdev;
    } my_dev;
    
    struct pci {
        struct cdev cdev;
        struct pci_dev *pdev;
    } pci;
};
```

and a pointer to an allocated `struct my_device`:

```
    struct my_device *mydev = kzalloc(sizeof(*mydev), GFP_KERNEL);
```

and a pointer to the `pci.pdev` member:

```
    struct pci_dev **ppdev = &mydev->pci.pdev;
```

then it is possible to convert that back to a pointer to the containing `struct my_device` using `container_of()`:

```
    struct my_device *myd = container_of(ppdev, struct my_device, pci.pdev);
```

OP has something like this:

```
    struct my_device *mydev = kzalloc(sizeof(*mydev), GFP_KERNEL);
    mydev->pci.pdev = pcidev;
```

and is trying to get back to the `struct my_device` from the pointer `pcidev` as follows:

```
    struct my_device *mydev = container_of(&pcidev, struct my_device, pci.pdev); /* wrong! */
```

That does not work because `&pcidev` is the address of the `pcidev` variable, not the address of the original `mydev->pci.pdev` member.

---

The Linux kernel allows a PCI device driver to associate an arbitrary `void *` value with a PCI device. That is normally done in the PCI device driver's `probe()` handler, something like this:

```
    pci_set_drvdata(pcidev, mydev);
```

Then until the PCI device is removed from the driver, or the driver calls `pci_set_drvdata` with some other value, the pointer can be retrieved by a call to `pci_get_drvdata()`:

```
    struct my_device *mydev = pci_get_drvdata(pcidev);
```

---

More generally, `pci_set_drvdata()` and `pci_get_drvdata()` are just wrappers around `dev_set_drvdata()` and `dev_get_drvdata()` that associate an arbitrary `void *` value with a `struct device`. The `struct pci_device` structure definition contains a member `struct device dev;`. `pci_set_drvdata(pcidev, ptr)` is equivalent to `dev_set_drvdata(&pcidev->dev, ptr)`, and `pci_get_drvdata(pcidev)` is equivalent to `dev_get_drvdata(&pcidev->dev)`.

Often, driver code has a pointer to a `struct device` that it knows is embedded within a `struct pci_dev`, and it can use `container_of()` to get a pointer to the containing `struct pci_dev`:

```
/* dptr is pointing the the struct device inside a struct pci_dev. */
static void foo(struct device *dptr)
{
    struct pci_dev *pcidev = container_of(dptr, struct pci_dev, dev);
    /* ... */
}
```

If the driver has previously used `pci_set_drvdata()` or `dev_set_drvdata()`, it can use `pci_get_drvdata()` or `dev_get_drvdata()` to retrieve the set value:

```
static void foo(struct device *dptr)
{
    struct pci_dev *pcidev = container_of(dptr, struct pci_dev, dev);
    struct my_device *mydev = pci_get_drvdata(pcidev);
    struct my_device *mydev1 = dev_get_drvdata(dptr);
    /* (mydev == mydev1) is true */
    struct pci_dev *pcidev1 = mydev->pci.pdev;
    /* (pcidev == pcidev1) is true assuming mydev->pci.pdev was previously set to pcidev */
    /* ... */
}
```

Although it works, it is probably bad style to mix `pci_set_drvdata()` with a previous call to `dev_get_drvdata()` or to mix `pci_get_drvdata()` with a previous call to `dev_set_drvdata()`.

Comment: Although it is not allowed to merely express thankfulness in a comment, I would like to make an exception here since this is the most incredible and helpful answer that I have ever got. Many thanks!