# Linux Misc Device: general protection fault at misc_deregister() on driver with private data allocation

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a simple character driver in Linux for educational purposes of learning Linux kernel development. For this, I create a misc device and dynamically allocate its private data during my `misc_init()` and free them in `misc_exit()`. Even though the driver has no other code (yet), I get a general protection fault from the kernel when doing `sudo rmmod sepehr`.

This is my driver code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

// Private data structure
struct sepehr_private {
    struct mutex mtx;
    char *message;
    size_t size;
};

// File Operations - Open
static int sepehr_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return 0;
}

// File Operations - Release
static int sepehr_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return 0;
}

// File Operations - Read
static ssize_t sepehr_read(struct file *file, char *buffer, size_t len,
               loff_t *offset)
{
    return 0;
}

// File Operations - Write
static ssize_t sepehr_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, size_t len,
                loff_t *offset)
{
    return len;
}

// File Operations - Ioctl
static long sepehr_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    return 0;
}

// File Operations - Llseek
static loff_t sepehr_llseek(struct file *file, loff_t offset, int whence)
{
    return 0;
}

// File operations structure
static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = sepehr_open,
    .release = sepehr_release,
    .read = sepehr_read,
    .write = sepehr_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl = sepehr_ioctl,
    .llseek = sepehr_llseek,
};

// Misc device structure
static struct miscdevice misc_device = {
    .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    .name = "sepehr",
    .fops = &fops,
    .mode = 0666,
};

// Module init function
static int __init misc_init(void)
{
    int ret;
    struct sepehr_private *priv;

    priv = kzalloc(sizeof(*priv), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!priv) {
        printk("Unable to allocate memory for sepehr_private\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    mutex_init(&priv->mtx);
    priv->message = NULL;
    priv->size = 0;

    ret = misc_register(&misc_device);
    if (ret) {
        kfree(priv); // free the memory in case of registration failure
        return ret;
    }

    misc_device.this_device->driver_data = priv;

    return ret;
}

// Module exit function
static void __exit misc_exit(void)
{
    struct sepehr_private *priv = misc_device.this_device->driver_data;
    misc_deregister(&misc_device);

    mutex_destroy(&priv->mtx);
    kfree(priv->message);
    kfree(priv);
}

module_init(misc_init);
module_exit(misc_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sepehr");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("It's fake. Just for testing");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
```

When I load and unload repeatedly (as I would to test out new parts of code I would write) eventually I would get a SIGSEGV from `rmmod`. Then, driver is in a stuck mode and cannot be removed, and I can only reboot my VM. It's very curious also that this would happen after I `insmod` and `rmmod` a few times, not necessarily on the first try. So I suspect this is some undefined behavior with a dangling pointer or a memory corruption.

Here's the full output from dmesg to inspect, but in short, it encounters a general protection fault, at `misc_deregister`, and the `RIP` is at `strlen()`, from `kstrdup()`, from `device_get_devnode()`.

dmesg full log:

```
[ 1041.925268] sepehr: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 1041.925585] sepehr: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 1044.099974] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x7304240700013200: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP PTI
[ 1044.100002] CPU: 1 PID: 2300 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G           OE      6.3.12-100.fc37.x86_64 #1
[ 1044.100016] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 1044.100027] RIP: 0010:strlen+0x4/0x30
[ 1044.100039] Code: f7 75 ec 31 c0 c3 cc cc cc cc 48 89 f8 c3 cc cc cc cc 0f 1f 40 00 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 f3 0f 1e fa <80> 3f 00 74 14 48 89 f8 48 83 c0 01 80 38 00 75 f7 48 29 f8 c3 cc
[ 1044.100063] RSP: 0018:ffffa70fc140fd60 EFLAGS: 00010206
[ 1044.100073] RAX: ffff94cff6bc5b00 RBX: 7304240700013200 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1044.100084] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 7304240700013200
[ 1044.100095] RBP: ffff94cff6fed000 R08: ffffa70fc140fdb0 R09: 000000008020001d
[ 1044.100106] R10: ffffa70fc140fdc8 R11: ffffa70fc140fdd0 R12: 0000000000000cc0
[ 1044.100116] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 1044.100127] FS:  00007ff614371740(0000) GS:ffff94d19c440000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1044.100139] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1044.100148] CR2: 000055cb8d5e7468 CR3: 000000013687a006 CR4: 00000000000306e0
[ 1044.100160] Call Trace:
[ 1044.100168]  <TASK>
[ 1044.100175]  ? die_addr+0x36/0x90
[ 1044.100187]  ? exc_general_protection+0x1be/0x420
[ 1044.100198]  ? asm_exc_general_protection+0x26/0x30
[ 1044.100211]  ? strlen+0x4/0x30
[ 1044.100218]  kstrdup+0x1d/0x70
[ 1044.100229]  device_get_devnode+0x70/0xe0
[ 1044.100241]  devtmpfs_delete_node+0x53/0xa0
[ 1044.100252]  device_del+0x338/0x3e0
[ 1044.100264]  device_unregister+0x17/0x60
[ 1044.100273]  misc_deregister+0x70/0xe0
[ 1044.100285]  misc_exit+0x1c/0xf20 [sepehr]
[ 1044.100296]  __do_sys_delete_module.constprop.0+0x19b/0x2f0
[ 1044.100309]  do_syscall_64+0x5f/0x90
[ 1044.100319]  ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
[ 1044.100328]  ? exc_page_fault+0x74/0x170
[ 1044.100337]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x72/0xdc
[ 1044.100348] RIP: 0033:0x7ff613d2fe5b
[ 1044.100367] Code: 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d d5 5f 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa b8 b0 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d a5 5f 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[ 1044.100390] RSP: 002b:00007ffedc00adb8 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000b0
[ 1044.100402] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055cb8d5dc760 RCX: 00007ff613d2fe5b
[ 1044.100430] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000800 RDI: 000055cb8d5dc7c8
[ 1044.100441] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 1999999999999999 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1044.100451] R10: 00007ff613da0ac0 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 00007ffedc00b010
[ 1044.100461] R13: 00007ffedc00c799 R14: 000055cb8d5dc2a0 R15: 00007ffedc00b018
[ 1044.100473]  </TASK>
[ 1044.100478] Modules linked in: sepehr(OE-) nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_set rfkill nf_tables nfnetlink qrtr sunrpc snd_intel8x0 intel_rapl_msr snd_ac97_codec intel_rapl_common ac97_bus snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm snd_timer rapl joydev snd i2c_piix4 vboxguest soundcore fuse loop zram xfs crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 serio_raw vmwgfx e1000 video drm_ttm_helper ttm wmi ata_generic pata_acpi scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua dm_multipath
[ 1044.100508] Unloaded tainted modules: sepehr(OE):1 [last unloaded: sepehr(OE)]
[ 1044.102506] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[ 1044.102785] RIP: 0010:strlen+0x4/0x30
[ 1044.103049] Code: f7 75 ec 31 c0 c3 cc cc cc cc 48 89 f8 c3 cc cc cc cc 0f 1f 40 00 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 f3 0f 1e fa <80> 3f 00 74 14 48 89 f8 48 83 c0 01 80 38 00 75 f7 48 29 f8 c3 cc
[ 1044.103788] RSP: 0018:ffffa70fc140fd60 EFLAGS: 00010206
[ 1044.104058] RAX: ffff94cff6bc5b00 RBX: 7304240700013200 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1044.104328] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 7304240700013200
[ 1044.104577] RBP: ffff94cff6fed000 R08: ffffa70fc140fdb0 R09: 000000008020001d
[ 1044.104825] R10: ffffa70fc140fdc8 R11: ffffa70fc140fdd0 R12: 0000000000000cc0
[ 1044.105313] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 1044.105574] FS:  00007ff614371740(0000) GS:ffff94d19c440000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1044.105831] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1044.106087] CR2: 000055cb8d5e7468 CR3: 000000013687a006 CR4: 00000000000306e0
```

As a reference, I tested this on the Fedora kernel of `6.3.12-100.fc37.x86_64`, on two separate, clean VMs. Both same issue. I've tried many things, but I cannot find a solution or see where I'm going wrong.

My original driver code was much longer, and I stripped it down to exactly this. Removing the data allocation also absolves the driver from encountering the errors. My error has to be from the way I assign the data. I explored other misc drivers in from elixir.bootlin.com and couldn't find a similar example to reproduce for my code either. I would like to know if there's a proper way to initialize data for the driver that wouldn't oops the kernel this way.

Edit: I should also mention that I would like to keep my data dynamically allocated, and not tracked as a global static non-const variable.

Comment: Does it happen too when you initialize `priv->message` to something non-NULL?

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't matter because `kfree()` checks for NULL

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Exactly. I can only think that the `strlen` error is originating from the module name, but it's a string literal. How can that be an issue? And if that's not the issue, what is `strlen` even calling?

Comment: When device is created it uses driver data for its own purposes: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5-rc3/source/drivers/char/misc.c#L242 (see fourth parameter). You simply overwritten the correct value with a garbage `misc_device.this_device->driver_data = priv;`. You need to understand what you are doing. Also useful to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27926630/2511795.

Comment: If you wish, you can check that answer, I don't need your bounty :-)

Comment: @0andriy Good references! Much appreciated. Would you know what I need to instead, then? Naturally there's the approach of letting `priv` live as a global variable and reference it throughout the program from, say, `write` and `read` and whatnot. Is there a way I can avoid having a non-const global variable hold the state of my driver?

Comment: You need a global variable to hold your data (either as a single pointer in case of only single instance of the device or a container, like linked list, the latter is usually preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this_device->driver_data` member is used internally, so you shouldn't override it.