# Passing data from kernel probe to character device file operations

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently using a global variable initialised during probe, it is said to be a bad practice.

I can save data to the driver using `dev_set_drvdata`, however I don't know how to retrieve the saved data from a `struct file`/`struct inode`.

So what is the recommended way of passing data from kernel probe to character device file operations?

Comment: A character device file expects to receive data from a user process and  should give an error on a kernel address.  Kernel drivers should not be performing file operations at all.

Comment: It is not for performing file operations but rather for implementing the functions in `struct file_operations` of the character device

Comment: Your `open` handler can use `inode->i_rdev` to determine the major/minor device number and perhaps use a global table to map minor device numbers to probed devices' data. Alternatively, it can use `inode->i_cdev` to get a pointer to the `struct cdev`, which is useful if your `probe` function calls `cdev_add()` for each probed device and embeds the `struct cdev` in device private data, so that `container_of()` can be used to get the device private data from the embedded `struct cdev`. Once you have the pointer to the device private data, the `open` handler can store it in `file->private_data`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the possible use of dev\_set\_drvdata and dev\_get\_drvdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800337/what-is-the-possible-use-of-dev-set-drvdata-and-dev-get-drvdata)

Comment: @IanAbbot, could you provide an example of this as an answer?

Comment: @0andriy I read this one already, it doesn't really answer the question.
My question could be reformulated as how do I get the `struct device` needed by `dev_get_drvdata` in file operations (`open`/`read`/etc) provided to my character device?

Comment: An example driver using the embedded `struct cdev` approach is "drivers/misc/hpilo.[ch]". It's per-device private data `struct ilo_hwinfo` contains a `struct cdev cdev` member. `ilo_probe()` calls `cdev_add` on that `cdev`. It's a little unusual in that the hardware device supports several (`max_ccb`) "slots", each with its own minor device number, and it cheats a bit when assigning minor device numbers to these slots because it only supports one device. The file operation handlers use `ip->i_cdev` to find the device data, and `ip->i_rdev` (via `iminor(ip)`) for device minor number.